# Form file field formatting with jquery filestyle

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make custom Form File field by using jquery filestyle plugin & its working fine, but I am getting problem in IE7 (its functioning but formatting not coming up).

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See below link it is useful to you

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: :( my all form field setup are finished. just to solve the image shown problem in IE7 button